# How to use ssh and sudo together in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I haven't been able to find a question that describes this specific scenario.

I am trying to execute a very basic bash script to retrieve logging from multiple machines. I am running the script locally but need to access an external machine via ssh, as well as sudo into a privileged user once on that machine...

```
ssh myuser@machine.net
sudo su  - privledged_user
cat logs > file.txt
```

Running this with sh -x reveals bash is getting stuck on the 'ssh' line. So I tried revising it to this:

```
ssh myuser@machine.net sudo su - privledged_user cat logs > file.txt
```

This also seems to stall indefinitely. Is there a better solution to this problem?? I don't see a way around using sudo su from what I can tell...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why the close vote ? This question is on topic: **managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks
, tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these**

Answer (score 5):

The way I achieve this in my current environment, is to run ssh with the `-t` flag which forces tty allocation, and to then run sudo -u root  within it, as follows:

```
ssh -t hostname << EOF
  command1
  sudo -u root command2
  sudo -u otheruser "command3 | command4"
  sudo -u root /bin/bash -c "command5; command6; command7"
  command8 && ( sudo -u otheruser /bin/bash -c "cmd1 ${1}; cmd2 {$2}" ) || echo cmd2 did not work

EOF
```

I have my account in sudoers on the remote side so that no password is required.

This example shows you different ways to do this within a single ssh session, including running multiple commands with bash or within a subshell. Note also that if you put the above code into an executable script, you can pass command line arguments ($1 and $2) to ssh and these will be expanded and then referenced on the remote side.

Comment: Unfortunately because I don't manage the remote server, I *believe* I'm stuck using sudo su here. Would that still work in this format?

Comment: yes it will work too. you can enter the password when prompted.

Comment: I've tried:  

ssh -t mrhyner@stg-app3.indeed.net << EOF
sudo su - adcentrl
egrep 'ERROR\|WARN' /home/adcentrl/cronjobs/logs/*/*

EOF  

But I received: "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."

Comment: perfectly okay. ignore that warning and proceed. if you want you can disable "RequireTty" in /etc/sudoers on the remote end

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want or can't stop sudo from asking you the password, one simple trick is to *read it locally* and store it in a local variable:

```
read -p 'Password: ' -s password

ssh -t user@1.2.3.4 <<EOF
  echo "$password" | sudo -S whoami
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

If sudo is configured to allow passwordless commands, this should do what you want:

```
ssh myuser@machine.net "sudo su - privileged_user -c 'cat logs'" > file.txt
```

or

```
ssh myuser@machine.net "sudo su - privileged_user -c 'cat logs > file.txt'"
```

depending on whether you want `file.txt` file be created locally or remotely.

Otherwise, here is a way to pass the remote user's password to `sudo`:

```
echo mrhyner_password | \
  ssh mrhyner@test-server.net \
  "sudo -S su - adcentrl -c 'egrep ERROR\|WARN /home/adcentrl/cronjobs/logs/*/*'"
```

Comment: Very interesting. However using ssh without -t tells me "no tty present". Adding in -t removes this error but doesn't seem to honor 'sudo su' as it prompts me for a password. Here's specifically what I'm doing:

    ssh -t  mrhyner@test-server.net "sudo su - adcentrl -c egrep "ERROR\|WARN" /home/adcentrl/cronjobs/logs/*/*"

This gives me:

    bash: WARN: command not found
    [sudo] password for mrhyner:

Comment: Sorry, I apparently don't know how to format my comments in this thing

Comment: I was assuming sudo was configured to be passwordless for your remote account.

Comment: and you are missing extra single quotes.

Comment: It is, which caused me to reason that bash isn't honoring the ssh command for some reason. It's acting like I'm trying to sudo from my local host =\

Comment: I saw that too...fixed it with the same result

Comment: Ugh, using your most recent suggestion, it immediately prompts me for a sudo password for mrhyner. However, if I run ssh -t mrhyner@test-server.net, press ENTER, and then 'sudo su - adcentrl' and press ENTER, it works fine.

Comment: I updated my suggestion. Is it closer to your expectations ?